# Ruby on Rails 4 editing multiple records integers at once

Tags: forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a question regarding editing multiple records of a model on the same form.
Thus far through my research I have seen Boolean changed and functions applied to record values. However, i have yet to see the ability to change integers in selected records to any value a user desires.

Basically, I wish to create a table listing the id, integer value and last edit time that gives the user the ability to change any/all of the integer values on submission to value they entered into the form (i.e. Edit Multiple).

Thanks

Comment: This sounds like a simple CRUD operation within the appropriate controller for that page.

Comment: can you expand on this further?

Comment: For example:http://railscasts.com/episodes/165-edit-multiple?view=asciicast but I wish to allow the user to change any/all the integer values to any value they wish. No apply a predetermined function.